# What is the best multi-account Twitter client?

Tags: configuration, gwibber, online-accounts, twitter

I used Gwibber in the past to follow two Twitter accounts I have. To distinguish between the two, it was possible to assign a different colour to each account.

Now I'm trying to use Gwibber again but the colour assign feature seems gone. Instead tweets are marked with a tiny twitter icon on the right ONLY when you hover to the right of a post.
[image]

Unfortunately the icon is the same for both accounts.

So my real question is: How do I distinguish posts in one twitter feed from the other? If Gwibber cannot do that any longer, is there a different Twitter client that can do the trick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option would be to use Polly.
It has great support for multiple twitter accounts.

Here is an article about the app:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/twitter-app-polly-adds-ubuntu-12-10-support
[image]

Although the article has download links / instructions you may want to get it from the official launchpad page:
https://launchpad.net/polly

Answer (score 1):

In the end I settled for Hotot client.

It manages accounts separately, that is, one by one, but it is functional and user-friendly.

It is found in the repos but I had problems with that version. Then I installed it from [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~hotot-team/+archive/ppa) and everything was fine.

Comment: Unfortunately hotot was [discontinued in February this year](http://hotot.org/this-project-has-been-discontinued/).